# Android custom row layout not showing up in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

I can't see the row that I've added to a list view and am wondering if it has something to do with my layout or ListViewAdapter.  In debug I can see that my array is filled with the data passed to my ArrayList  playerList, and I see the data in Toast but nothing shows up on screen.
MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtV_battingOrder_Title"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_AddButton_title" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.89" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

New Row Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV_player_input_position_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:width="180dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Edit_Title"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_edit_player_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtV_player_input_position_title"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtV_player_input_position_title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/bnt_Edit_title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom ListViewAdapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{   
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<String> playerList;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<String> playerList) {  
        super();

        this.playerList = playerList;
        this.inflater =     (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override  
    public int getCount() {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return playerList.size();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return 0;  
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
      public TextView text;
      public Button edit;
    }
    @Override  
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        String player = playerList.get(position);
        View vi=convertView;

        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_player_view, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
//        assign components from new_player_view
//        TextView playerInfo = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtV_player_input_position_title);   
        holder.text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtV_player_input_position_title);
        holder.edit = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_Edit_Title);
//        Button editButton = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_Edit_Title);
        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.editPlayerButtonListener);
        holder.text.setText(player);
        //playerInfo.setText("this is a test");
        vi.setTag(holder);

        return vi;  
    }
```

Comment: what kind of adapter are you extending?

Comment: public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Comment: post the whole adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using too much the weight property in your `xml`.. you should use it wisely, I don't know why the `RelativeLayout` has the `weight` 1 but anyway, I think the issue you have might be one of the following:

- make sure `getCount()` returns > 0
- make sure your are using this method to do the inflate: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_player_view, parent, false);`
- change the row layout to the follwing:

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:padding="5dp" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtV_player_input_position_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"/>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_Edit_Title"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_edit_player_width"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
          android:padding="3dp"
          android:text="@string/bnt_Edit_title" />
  ```

And the main layout `ListView` to:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I hope something will help you, otherwise, please post the full code of the adapter.

**EDIT:**

Please try to look at [this](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/07/android-listview-tutorial.html) example of ViewHolder pattern implementation, that is working and it should help you implement yours better.

Comment: I tried all the changes. Still the same output (nothing visible)  I had the weight in there from my previous attempt at same project where I added a table row to a tablelayout (I think). I have been trying to get this to work for a long time now.

Comment: I updated my answer, are you sure that getCount() is > 0? Or can you see also see the button btn_AddButton_title on your screen? Because the adapter you use seems to be fine in my opinion..

Comment: I implemented changes to my adapter from the tut that you suggest.  It didn't change the ouput but it did give me an idea to create a loop in my mainActivity to add to my list and SUCCESS! My list showed all the items that were add.  NOW I just have to figure why.  But I am slowly chipping away at the problem. I appreciate your help.  And before I created the loop in onCreate - NO the button was not showing up.

Comment: Ok, then I think you're problem was on how you used the adapter maybe :)

Comment: A HUGE THANK YOU! Cata.  I figure it out.  The notifyDataSetChange was the key. I had comment it out to when trying to debug - uncommmented and magic happened!

Answer (score 1):

You have set layout_weight as 0.89 without setting the weightSum for the parent layout. Set `android:weightSum = "1"` for your parent LinearLayout